# Is it possible to stuff a Bag of Holding inside another Bag of Holding?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

And then stuff that [Bag of Holding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-holding) into another Bag of Holding, and so on *ad infinitum*?

Earlier editions of D&D prohibit this. I haven't found similar rules for 5th edition, but perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place.

If putting a Bag of Holding inside another Bag of Holding is allowed, conceivably a player character could carry a king's ransom in gold or an entire army on his back given enough Bags of Holding.

Comment: Related - same question, but for portable holes: [Two portable holes would rupture if one were inside the other, right?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56087/23970)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### Yes, but that'll destroy both and create other havoc.

> Placing a *bag of holding* into an extradimensional space created by a *Heward's handy haversack*, *portable hole*, or similar item instantly destroys both items and opens a gate to the Astral plane.... (DMG p.154)

So the question, then, is whether a *bag of holding*, itself, creates such a space and is thus a *similar item*.

(And it's tempting to think that it's not: the *bag*'s own description doesn't say that the interior is extradimensional, just that it's larger than the outside. For comparison, both the *haversack* and the *hole* do explicitly say early in their descriptions that they create extradimensional spaces.)

But the bag *does* create an extradimensional space. We know this from the descriptions of the *handy haversack* and *portable hole*, each of which list the *bag of holding* as creating one of these dangerously-incompatible spaces.

See DMG pp. 153-4, 174, and 186-7 for all descriptions.

---

Later, [Mearls agrees](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/753684706135191552). Remember, his rulings are not authoritative, but rather are just the word of one *very* well-informed GM.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42463/discussion-on-answer-by-nitsua60-is-it-possible-to-stuff-a-bag-of-holding-inside).

Comment: "Very well informed" is an understatement. This is a DM that helped design dnd 5e. He knows the rules as intended better than anyone

Comment: well, that's why "very" is italicized =) And I'd say he knows the rules-as-intended better than all-but-one; much of Mearls' time is spent on larger brand-level things, where Crawford's *the* go-to for rules. I'm just parroting the sort of thing Mearls usually says whenever he's talking about rules: *"this is just what my ruling would be; Jeremy's the official guy."*

Comment: Sigh, my dreams of a PC carrying a million pounds of loot, or smuggling a thousand soldiers into the enemy castle in a bunch of bags of holding nested inside a *single 15 lb bag of holding* are squashed. :(

Comment: Not squashed, exploded :(