# What happens if a dismissed familiar takes a Bag of Holding with it?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, familiars, planes

[Assuming that you *can* use a familiar as a safety-deposit box (because the DM's has ruled so)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/61979/can-i-use-my-familiar-as-a-safety-deposit-box), how would this interact with an magic item that makes an extra-dimensional space?

What happens if you give your familiar a Bag of Holding, Portable Hole, or similar item, and then you dismiss your familiar to its pocket dimension? In particular, such items when put in *each other* tend to burst and cause problems. Does that happen in this case as well? If not, why not?

Comment: "What happens *if* my DM allows a dismissed familiar to take a bag of holding with it to its pocket dimension" is something I don't think can be answered within Good-Subjective per stack rules.  I suggest taking this question to a forum, like giantitp.com

Comment: The distinction you're drawing is based on putting (items containing) pocket dimensions within pocket dimensions, but it's not clear why you expect this to make a difference. If you quoted the rules and explained the expected issue it would be clearer, but in that case, see https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56087/two-portable-holes-would-rupture-if-one-were-inside-the-other-right (which is not a dupe, but *does* answer this).

Comment: TuggyNE, I think that the answer to that question has the solution I am looking for. Thank you! However, I do not think this should be marked as a duplicate because the answer found there is only a comment within an answer on a different issue.

If that information were put into a proper answer for this question with an explanation from the rules, that could be chosen as the correct answer.

Comment: Related: [bag of holding in another bag of holding](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84078/23970). (Spoiler: the answer is "BOOM.")

Answer (score 6):

**Nothing.**

The rules for the interaction between a Bag of Holding and a Portable Hole are specific to each other, and don't apply to any other type of planar travel. For example, there is no interaction between a Bag of Holding and a portal created by the Gate spell, or someone transported using Teleportation or Plane Shift.

Thus, there is no reason to think that a familiar's mode of transport would work any differently, so there is no interaction, by RAW.