# Is it safe to bring an item like a Bag of Holding into a Genie Warlock's Bottle?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, warlock

Since the Genie's Vessel is described as an object/vessel and never as an item, is it safe to bring a Portable Hole, Bag of Holding, or Heward's Handy Haversack into the bottle?
If your vessel is a ring per the examples, is it splitting hairs to not call it an item?

> **Genie's Vessel:** -- Tashas p.73
> The vessel is a Tiny object, and you can use it as a spellcasting focus for your warlock spells.

> **Bottled Respite:** -- Tashas p.74
> The interior of the vessel is an **extradimensional space** in the shape of a 20-foot-radius cylinder, 20 feet high, and resembles your vessel.

> **Bag of Holding:** -- DMG p.154
> Placing a bag of holding inside an **extradimensional space** created by a Heward's handy haversack, portable hole, or **similar item** instantly destroys both items and opens a gate to the Astral Plane.

Comment: Related: "[What happens if a dismissed familiar takes a Bag of Holding with it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105857)" and "[Does a bag of holding burst if brought into the space created by Rope Trick?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105932)" and "[Does a Quiver of Ehlonna create a gate to the Astral Plane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138956)" and "[What happens when you put a bag of devouring inside of a bag of holding?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114905)"

Comment: More generally, the question boils down to: Is an object an item?

Answer (score 17):

#### Proceed with caution: Ask your DM before trying this.

You have made all of the relevant observations: the genie vessel is a **similar item** that creates an extra dimensional space. *Rules as written* this is going to punch your ticket to the Astral Sea.

That said, it wouldn’t be a terrible thing to permit this interaction without the usual consequences, *as long as you are prepared as a DM to deal with the shenanigans that might follow*.

Comment: Is the Genie's Vessel and **Item**?  Nowhere in the subclass is it called as such, just an object.  I am fairly certain a door is an object but not an item, so is it possible this is purposely not an item to get around this issue?

Comment: @Mavoc I think we’re splitting hairs if we try to figure this out by distinguishing between an item and an object. You’re welcome to propose that in an answer of your own, but I don’t think it’s a good solution.

Comment: Mainly I'm curious if there is any official verbiage somewhere defining those terms.

Comment: @Mavoc There's a question on here somewhere about Wish where one of the answers might interest you: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/158657/11136 .Essentially, D&D 5e is meant to be read in plain English, not as a mesh of interlocking keywords like 4e. There's also [What is considered an object?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95532/what-is-considered-an-object).

Comment: Trying to differentiate between **object** and **item** isn't even close to splitting hairs, it's simply a complete fallacy. The two terms are synonymous, and saying that something is an object but *not* an item (or vice versa) is a mistake at best, and a poor attempt at power-gaming at worst.