# Can a Rope Trick Spell Scroll and a Bag of Holding open up the gate to the Astral Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, planes, astral

I am aware that the *rope trick* spell alone cannot open a gate to the Astral Plane when combined with a *bag of holding*, as per this Q&A:
[Does a bag of holding burst if brought into the space created by Rope Trick?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105932/does-a-bag-of-holding-burst-if-brought-into-the-space-created-by-rope-trick)

But according to the [*bag of holding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-holding)'s description:

> Placing a bag of holding inside an extradimensional space created by a Handy Haversack, Portable Hole, or **similar item** instantly destroys both items and opens a gate to the Astral Plane

Considering the extradimensional space would have been created by an item, would a *spell scroll* of *rope trick* count in this scenario?

Comment: Hi MadameMindFlayer, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Answer (score 11):

### Regardless of how the *rope trick* spell is cast, a portal to the Astral Plane will not appear when a Bag of Holding enters the extradimensional space

The Bag of Holding states:

> Placing a bag of holding inside an extradimensional space created by a Handy Haversack, Portable Hole, or **similar item** instantly destroys **both items** and opens a gate to the Astral Plane...

First off, we already know that a normal *rope trick* room would not create a portal to the Astral Plane because the room is not an item, nor was it created by an item.

What happens when the extradimensional space is created by an item (in this case a spell scroll) is perhaps uncertain, but there are two pieces of evidence that this would have the same results:

1. The Bag of Holding requires that the other plane be created by a *similar* item. I would not say that a spell scroll is similar to a Bag of Holding in the same way that Portable Holes and Handy Haversacks are. The latter two effectively *are* extradimensional spaces while a spell scroll certainly is not.
2. The Bag of Holding says that both items are destroyed, however in this case the spell scroll has already been destroyed, so this is somewhat unusual.
   If we said the scroll does get destroyed then extending this situation to other items creates problems. For example: A Ring of Spell Storing. The ring would be destroyed, no matter the distance between it and the extradimensional space. Not only is destroying a magic item incredibly powerful, but where would the portal appear?

It does not matter how *rope trick* is cast; a portal to the Astral Plane would not appear because the item casting the spell is not *similar* to a Bag of Holding to the same degree that a Portable Hole and a Handy Haversack are.

Comment: It's definitely "similar" in that it creates an extradimensional space, yah?

Comment: @markwells Bags of Holding don't create one, they *are* one. The items don't scream "similar" to me when the other two listed items are far far *more* similar

Comment: Similarity in the original intent is to suggest 'a way to hold adventurer's stuff'.
The reason for this restriction is so that characters don't get infinite free carrying capacity.

Answer (score -2):

The difference is that a BoH, Portable Hole, and a HHS are PERMANENT pocket dimensions where the ropetrick is a temporary one.

If I were the DM and my players were using Ropetrick to cheese all my encounters I would rule it that the Rope that is enchanted to make the ropetrick spell work is the item generating the pocket space and if I can get even a bit of the rope into a bag of holding ( say by having a goblin sit by where the rope keeps appearing and disappearing while holding a bag of holding with a held action to put the bag around the end of the rope) then I would say it destroys the bag, the rope, both dimensions, the players and that unfortunate goblin all go to the Astral and there's an Astral Dreadnaught waiting for them, roll initiative with disadvantage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).