# What happens when you put a bag of devouring inside of a bag of holding?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, astral

According to the books, if you place a [bag of holding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-holding) within a [portable hole](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/portable-hole) or any other type of extra dimensional storing device, it creates a hole that opens up to the astral plane.

My question is what happens if you place a [bag of devouring](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-devouring) inside a bag of holding or any other extra dimensional storage device?

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84078/is-it-possible-to-stuff-a-bag-of-holding-inside-another-bag-of-holding

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56087/two-portable-holes-would-rupture-if-one-were-inside-the-other-right

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A Bag of Devouring is "a feeding orifice for a gigantic extradimensional creature", so what's inside it is still an extradimensional space, and should interact with a Bag of Holding the same as any other such device.

Which is to say, in the words of Kurt Vonnegut, '...a ripping sound like the opening of the zipper on the fly of God Almighty.'

Comment: Does the sudden astral gate & loss of a 'mouth' damage the extradimensional creature?

Comment: @RozzA That would be up to your DM to determine, since no such thing is mentioned in the text.

Comment: The bag of devouring is a creature ('s organ), not an item.

Comment: Well, it's in the DMG under "Magic *Items* A-Z", and listed as a wondrous *item* in the specific description, so I guess you can have an argument with the dev team about that, if you really want to.

Answer (score 0):

According to the item descriptions nothing would happen if you placed a *bag of devouring* into a *bag of holding*, but if the *bag of holding* were placed inside the *bag of devouring* it would then create a hole to the astral plane.

Not all items are created equally, they all don't share the same weaknesses is basically what I'm trying to say.

The rules are very careful to let you know if an item has a specific interactions with other items/situations, which is why the *bag of holding*, *portable hole*, and *handy haversack* all have a rule added to them specifically:

> Placing a *bag of holding* inside an extradimensional space created by a *handy haversack*, *portable hole*, or similar item instantly destroys both items and opens a gate to the Astral Plane. The gate originates where the one item was placed inside the other. Any creature within 10 feet of the gate is sucked through it to a random location on the Astral Plane. The gate then closes. The gate is one-way only and can't be reopened.

Other items and spells work like *deep pockets*, a ritual introduced in "Heroic Tier Rituals" (*Dragon* #405):

> For the duration of the ritual, five pockets or pouches sewn into the garment may each hold 50 pounds of weight or 5 cubic feet of volume (totaling 250 pounds). Items in the pockets do not change the garment's form or weight. Items may be retrieved from these pockets as a minor action. When the ritual ends, items remaining in the pockets appear in a pile at the garment-wearer's feet.

These are missing the additional rule. This makes it logical to assume that if clothing under the effect of a spell like *deep pockets* was placed in a *bag of holding*, nothing would happen, but like the *bag of devouring*, placing the *bag of holding* into the pockets of the clothes would cause the astral hole.

Comment: -1 : The bag of devouring says : "The bag can hold up to 30 cubic feet of matter. It acts as a bag of holding type I," and therefor you ARE putting a bag of holding into a bag of holding regardless of which one goes into the other.

Comment: @VoromirKadien: That's a quote from a different edition.  5e doesn't have multiple types of Bag of Holding, and https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Bag%20of%20Devouring says it can only hold 1 cubic foot of inanimate objects.  However, it does still say *If the bag is pierced or torn, it is destroyed, and anything contained within it is transported to a random Location on the Astral Plane.* which is the same wording as a 5e bag of holding.  So I think your ultimate point still applies, and this answer is not well supported by RAW.