# Does a Quiver of Ehlonna create a gate to the Astral Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, planes, astral

In the DMG, the Bag of Holding, Heward's Handy Haversack, and Portable Hole all contain the same language indicating that placing any one inside another (naming those three items by name "or similar item") creates a temporary gate to the Astral Plane, sucking all creatures within 10 feet there.

The Quiver of Ehlonna, like the other three, contains extradimensional spaces, but does not contain this paragraph. Does it work for creating one of these temporary gates?

Comment: related: [bag in bag](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84079/23970), [hole in hole](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/56088/23970), [bag and rope trick](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105932/23970), [bag in bag, devouring variant](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114907/23970), and many others

Answer (score 18):

### It will open a gate.

The key language is "similar."

The referenced description states:

> Placing the haversack inside an extradimensional space  created by a bag of holding, portable hole, or similar item instantly destroys both items and opens a gate to the Astral Plane.

The first three items, the *Bag of Holding*, *Heward's Haversack*, and the *Portable Hole* are all variations on a theme.  So the question is if the Quiver is similar to them:

- Like all three the Quiver of Ehlonna is bigger on the inside.
- Like all three the Quiver of Ehlonna can fit many items without ever changing its outer dimensions.
- Like all three the Quiver of Ehlonna can fit many items without ever changing its weight.
- Like the haversack the Quiver of Ehlonna allows you to simply pull out what you need without rooting around for it.
- Like all three the Quiver of Ehlonna is specifically described or referenced as using extradimensional space.

Considering that even the haversack, the hole and the bag have some differences I would rule that the quiver has enough similarities to be considered *similar* to these three items, and especially so because it is described as using extradimensional space. Hence, placing the Quiver in any of the others would open a gate to the Astral Plane.

Left unsaid is what happens if the quiver is ruptured.  The bag and the haversack each have different consequences for being ruptured while the hole and the quiver make no mention of it.

Comment: Nothing in the quoted text indicates that placing *the quiver* inside a similar item has any additional effect. Nothing in the text indicates that placing an extradimensional space inside a haversack has any additional effect, only the other way around.

Comment: "Similar language" does not equate to same result. If the item description does not specifically deal with rupturing or Astral gates, then those things do **not** happen.

Answer (score 6):

### It will not open a gate.

As you state it does not have such a paragraph resulting in the gate opening. If you could somehow place a *bag of holding* in the quiver, it would as the quiver is an...

> extradimensional space created by a ... similar item

... but the Quiver has no such property.

Comment: From meta-perspective this also makes sense, since you can't make "nested containers" with the quiver (it accepts only specific kinds of objects). There's no game-mechanical reason to prevent putting the quiver into a haversack or similar item.